# NPM missing argument #1 error when trying to install packages

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

Getting this error when trying to install packages using `npm install`. Seems like an issue with npm itself. I'm running this on Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon.

> npm ERR! Linux 5.4.0-42-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node"
> "/usr/bin/npm" "i" npm ERR! node v8.10.0 npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2 npm ERR!
> code EMISSINGARG
>
> npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1 npm ERR!
> typeerror     at andLogAndFinish
> (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3) npm ERR! typeerror
> at fetchPackageMetadata
> (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22) npm ERR!
> typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule
> (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12) npm ERR! typeerror     at
> /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7 npm ERR! typeerror     at
> /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50 npm ERR! typeerror
> at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12 npm ERR!
> typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish
> (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5) npm ERR! typeerror
> at returnAndAddMetadata
> (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7) npm ERR!
> typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument
> (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20) npm ERR!
> typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50 npm
> ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this
> error at: npm ERR! typeerror     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /home/theoko/Desktop/fatigue-app/npm-debug.log

Comment: does this solve your problem https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/681#issuecomment-640470740

Answer (score 3):

Had an outdated version of node installed (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/681#issuecomment-640470740).

Comment: a solution by Kentaro is described [here](https://weekendprojects.dev/posts/fixed-npm-install-error-missing-required-argument-1/)